# cross domain service call to retrieve some html causing IE security popup

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I am calling a web service using jquery which sits on another domain. The web service is returning some html. The problem is every time I make the service call I get a security popup in IE saying that you are accessing information which is not in control of the current site. I cannot use jsonp because the service is returning text/xml.

Is there a way to avoid this popup since changing the service call to return json is not something I control.

Thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope you can't to bypass the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless the web service implements [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing).